# g++ warning when using optional 'struct' keyword

Tags: c++, namespaces, struct, g++, compiler-warnings

If I write this program:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    struct bar {
        int x;
    };
}

int main (void) {
    struct foo::bar *a = new struct foo::bar;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it with:

```
g++ main.cxx -Wall -Wextra
```

It gives me this warning:

```
main.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cxx:10:39: warning: declaration ‘struct foo::bar’ does not declare anything [enabled by default]
```

However, if I take out the `struct` keyword after the `new` keyword:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {
    struct bar {
        int x;
    };
}

int main (void) {
    struct foo::bar *a = new foo::bar;
    delete a;
    return 0;
}
```

and compile it the same way, g++ outputs no warnings.  Why does g++ output that warning if I use the `struct` keyword?

Comment: Interestingly neither clang++ nor comeau complain about the syntax, and a cursory look into the standard (C++03) didn't help understand the problem either.

Comment: As it is only a warning, I hesitate to say bug - but a GCC bug? The code looks OK to me. Also, it is namespace associated - doing the same thing without a namespace does not produce a warning.

Answer (score 5):

In C++, the `struct` keyword defines a type, and the new type no longer needs the `struct` keyword.  This is one of the many differences between C and C++.

Comment: This explain why the latter code works, but not why the first code produced a warning.

Comment: I understand that it's unnecessary to use the keyword in C++; I say that it's optional in the thread title.  Thanks for responding though.

Comment: Is it optional? What does the standard have to say about that?

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64973255%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), the struct keyword is "is unnecessary once the type has been defined."  This is what I meant, so I apologize if I was being ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Examining the error:

> main.cxx:10:39: warning: declaration `‘struct foo::bar’` does not declare anything [enabled by default]

g++ thinks you're declaring a new `struct` with the name `foo::bar` instead of allocating memory of type `struct foo::bar`. My guess would be because g++ assumes any usage of `struct` that doesn't declare an lvalue is for the purpose of declaring a type.

Comment: I understand what you say, but if the compiler is considering that a new type is being declared, then it should bail out with an error, not produce a simple warning, as the standard explicitly states that you cannot declare new types in the new expression

Comment: @Adetque It is a good idea to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer, so others can have chance to reply. In this case, I think the answer you have accepted is wrong.

Comment: @David : Maybe we should just be happy that g++ is punishing users who treat C++ as C-with-classes. ;-P

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Ok, I will be sure to do that.

@ildjarn: I try to avoid treating it like that.  It's just a habit I have from C.

Answer (score 2):

Just to post the minimal code that does and does not illustrate the problem:

```
namespace N {
struct A {};
}

struct B {};

int main() {
    struct N::A * a  = new struct N::A; // problem
    struct B * b  = new struct B;       // ok
}
```

Personally, I think this is a small GCC bug, but I am not wise in the myriad ways of namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Note:

```
   struct foo::bar *a = new struct foo::bar;
// ^^^^^^ (1)
                        //  ^^^^^^ (2)
```

1. Not needed in C++

   - Putting struct here is a hangover from C and is no longer needed in C++
     As all the types are all in the same `namespace`.
     While in C structs had there own namespace separate from other types.
     It is allowed to retain backward compatibility with C.
2. struct here looks like it is forward declaring something.

In C++ the above is written as:

```
   foo::bar* a = new foo::bar;
```

// or preferably

```
   foo::bar* a = new foo::bar(); // This makes a difference if you don't define
                                 // a default constructor.
```

### From David (Below)

Important enough I think it needs to be in the answer rather than the comments:

```
namespace foo
{
    struct bar {};
    void bar() {}
}

int main()
{
    struct foo::bar* p = new struct foo::bar;
    // Needed here because the compiler can't tell the difference between
    // a struct and a function otherwise
}
```

Comment: 1. Not needed in C++, or needed, depending on the rest of the code: `namespace foo { struct bar {}; void bar() {} } int main() { struct foo:bar* p = new struct foo::bar; }`. In that particular convoluted example, the use of `struct` is needed in C++ to tell the compiler to search for `bar` in namespace `foo` but only in the set of user defined types --and avoid other types of identifiers, like functions or variables.